# How to distinguish the patched multiple records from other?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I used Patch and Forall function to upload multiple records to SharePoint, but these records should be separated from others. My idea is  creating a new column which is called "UploadID" in the Sharepoint list. It should include all uploaded records at once. But how to create this column? It should be a unique column?

Comment: what do you mean but these records should be separated from others? each upload of a document to sharepoint is unique and it has it's own ID?

Comment: @AnkUser Hi, I mean for example, I patched the three records(ID1, ID2,ID3), and I patched an other two records(ID4, ID5), the first group should have a unique value(GroupID A?) to distinguish with the second group(Group B?), how can we do it？

Comment: I don't Think you have something like group based on your patch, as mentioned for every record you will get the ID and you will have to work with it

Comment: @AnkUser, Hi mate, Yes, based on the ID we can work for each records, but once we patch multiple records, we can not distinguish these with other patched records

Comment: unfortunately you will have to come up with logic so that your patch will return you ID of each newly created document and then you have to handle logic to distinguish

Comment: @AnkUser,Hi, do you have ideas? My first thought was to get the time when the user launched the app